# Unable to use script tag in Content Editor and Script Editor

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

This issue is happening from client PCs only. If I open the browser on server machine using RDP then it works. Here's what's happening.

1. Edit page
2. Add Content Editor or Script Editor
3. Write code `<script></script>` or `<script language="javascript">alert("hello world");</script>`
4. Press "Save" button on ribbon to save page
5. "The page cannot be displayed" error is shown in browser. Tested in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

But when I do same operation on IE on SharePoint server itself then it works fine.

Is it due to some security/firewall/AD/browser policy?

Comment: Hi Frank, it is always advisable to create a .txt file or .html in any library and then reference the link to your content editor webpart. try writing <script>##your code##</script> and see if it works.

Comment: If you reload the page after seeing this, does it load properly?

Comment: Yes refreshing it works fine because those scripts tags are removed.

Answer (score -1):

Use your javascript code directly in Script Editor without `<script></script>`

This will solve your issue

Comment: Doesn't work. Script Editor treats it as text.

Comment: This is wrong. You need the script tags.